# CSS possible to overlap margins like `display:block` but with `display:inline-block`

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a `inline-block` elements margins overlap link `display:block` does?

The following snippet has the desired margin but is `display:block`

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 30px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

The following snippet has the desired `display` but the margin don't merge.

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I have gone through all `display` values and none of them seem to product the desired affect.

The result should look exactly like [@Praveen Kumar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37074246/2273611) but this is specific to the example above.

Comment: Don't give margins on the right.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way. Give a `margin-left` and for the `:first-child` alone, remove the `margin-left`. Or better way, use `margin` only on one side:

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 30px;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Also, you might be looking for [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). That should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking for a way which i don't have to target the margin values individually.

Comment: @TarranJones I understand, but border collapsing can be done. Not sure about the `margin`. And this is how people have a use case.

Comment: "collapsing" thank you, knowing the correct terminology helps a lot. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: yea, no prob. could you just mention "margin collapsing" in your answer and stick that link in please.

Comment: @TarranJones Done.